# Where is the Windows forum?

Tags: support, site-scope

I use Apple and Windows products and love giving technical support on both of them.  I found Ask Different to help people with their Apple products and it's great!  However, I have searched far and wide for a Windows Stack Exchange, but I cannot find one.

Is there a Windows stack exchange or is this something I could suggest on Area 51?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://superuser.com/ is probably the best place to ask Windows question on the SE sites.

Comment: There it is!  Thank you!  I always saw superuser and thought Linux.

Comment: @Salocor If you are unsure you can always have a look at the "What topics can I ask about here?" page in the Help Center of the respective site, or just browse the existing questions or tags.